# how to add conditional ngClass if durationTime is less than 1 hour or more

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Trying to add conditional `ngClass` to determine whether the `CollectionFrom` is less than 1 hour or more then add specific class for either.

```
var awaitingPicking = [
  {
   "id": "2452",
   "OrderLineGroups": [
     {
       "CollectionDetails": {
         "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-21T13:00:00.317"
       }
     }
   ]
  },
{
   "id": "2454",
   "OrderLineGroups": [
     {
       "CollectionDetails": {
         "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-24T12:55:00.317"
       }
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

Using moment.js to convert the difference between currentTime and `CollectionFrom` time

```
for(var i = 0; i < awaitingPicking.length; i++){
  var a = moment(awaitingPicking[i].OrderLineGroups[0].CollectionDetails.CollectionFrom);
  var b = moment(new Date())
   this.thirtyMins = a.diff(b, 'minutes');
  console.log(this.thirtyMins, a.diff(b, 'minutes') + 'minute(s) left');
}
```

And in tempalte, here's a pseudo code condition I have in mind and end result. For some reason its adding `halfHour` to every button which it should only add on the button that meets the condition.

```
 <div *ngFor="let prepare of awaitingPicking" id="prepareOrder"> 
   <button [ngClass]="{'halfHour':thirtyMins < 60, 'moreThanHour': thirtyMins > 60}"> {{ prepare.Id }}</button>
</div>
```

My problem is that the `ngClass` condition seems to be wrong and its only taking 1 condition either both are `< 60` or `>60`, and couldn't figure out the work around.

[Sample Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mxdV1n6pL6Lw1wuBbNlh?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check the date/time different per value no? So I've added a function which does this and returns the value based on the time difference and sets the class. Updated plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZnhdinsXOd6Jk0G1nBeO?p=preview)

```
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of inputArray" [ngClass]="{
        'moreThan': checkTime(item.OrderLineGroups[0].CollectionDetails.CollectionFrom) === 'moreThan',
    'lessThan': checkTime(item.OrderLineGroups[0].CollectionDetails.CollectionFrom) === 'lessThan'
      }">
    {{item.id}} {{item.OrderLineGroups[0].CollectionDetails.CollectionFrom}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

And the function looks like this :-

```
public checkTime(time) {
    var a = moment(time);
    var b = moment(new Date());
    if (a.diff(b, 'minutes') < 60) {
      return "moreThan";
    } else {
      return "lessThan";
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to refresh/detect the UI template when the duration time is nearing to end? I forked your plnkr and created 3 conditions with 3 different classes, so it changes class when it meets the conditions but have to refresh the whole page for the class to take effect. https://plnkr.co/edit/TxncCFU8B3IF4PGJyuNe?p=preview

Comment: Actually I think it does change automatically, thanks

Comment: Btw would a switch case be better if I have more conditions?

Comment: With a switch case you have to know what the value is going to be, as you're using greater than or equal to, if statements are the way to go.